Is there a way to scan other colors except for (red, green, blue) precisely using a TCS34725 color sensor?
I am trying to make a color scanner using a TCS34725 color sensor that scans the colors of clothes. While it works rather fine when scanning primary colors, it does not give accurate readings when I start to scan clothes of other colors. For example if I scan a dark green T-shirt and convert the RGB value that the sensor provides it's more of a dark blue instead. I would expect to get a close RGB value that is similar to color of the clothing piece that was scanned. I am illuminating my target with the use of a white LED and I am using reflection
I tried a different sensor, the AS7262, but without any success. I also tried to perform white calibration by scanning something white before scanning other colors, but again it did not work.

How does it not give accurate readings? Please edit your question to describe what you expect, what you see, and why you believe it is wrong. While you're at it, describe how you're illuminating your target, and whether you're using transmission or reflection.

The answer here is obviously yes. What you may need to look into from the datasheet is some sort of color spectral responsivity chart. Red, green, and blue are simply components of lights. Everything you see in real life will have a percentage of red, green, and blue colors that you see. You may need to do some experiments to get sensor ADC responses under various exposed colors, lighting intensities, and beam angles.

maybe the t-shirt is actually blue ... maybe the green and blue channels are transposed

The LED illuminator may not have a uniform white spectrum.  You may need to use an incandescent halogen lamp with a known color temperature.

Can you provide a datasheet for the "white" LED? I'd be surprised if the spectrum is anywhere near even. Most white LEDs are blue with phosphors to give out some longer wavelengths but are very uneven. The higher intensity of the blue part of the spectrum would account for what you've described.

You will need to calibrate the sensor because it will not give a linear frequency response. For more accuracy at the lower end of the cost range, a google for "raspberry pi spectrometer" may give you ideas.

A white LED only looks white to your eyes. Generally a white LED is nothing more than a blue LED with a yellow phosphor. The blue is a sharp spectrum peak and also used to energize the yellow phosphor. The phosphorus emits a much boader spectrum around yellow. Modern LEDs intended for lighting applications may have a more pleasant spectrum though. The point is, the blue light gets mixed with yellow light just in correct proportions that you perceive it as white. There is not much red or green light emitted from the phosphorus so your sensor can't detect them properly.
So yes, everything is illuminated with narrowband blue light and broader band yellow light. That is what the sensor picks up. Your eyes see objects in somewhat same colour than in sunlight which is the reference for continuous white spectrum of light. The LED only looks white because it has a spectrum that triggers the three different types of spectral sensors in your eyes in same proportions than real white light would. But since the LED spectrum is obviously worse and peaky, the colour rendering index is worse. Some color frequencies of the spectrum are not there and object cannot reflect a clour that is not there coming out of the LED.
The problem is likely better solved with an RGB LED as a light source, which actually emits three different sharp spectral peaks. Or any amount of discrete LEDs as light source.
The problem of RGB LED is that it still does not emit e.g. yellow or cyan light at all. If the material is yellow and it reflects only yellow light but not red, green or blue light, your sensor will see just black.
